# Failed to compile .c file generated by cython

Tags: python, cython

I'm using `cython` to convert my python file into c file, but when I tried to compile the c file, it failed for me.

```
Python.h: No such file or directory
       #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

I read this post: [Cython Fatal Error: Python.h No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668675/cython-fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

But I can't understand it. I tried using `#include <Python.h>` instead of `#include "Python.h` it also failed for me.

Any solution? Thank you.

Comment: Go to the post you linked and read the second answer.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Sorry, but how do I install sudo? I tried `apt-get` but looks like apt-get needs to install, too. And another method `yum` also needs installation. But all I have now is `pip`.

Comment: See second answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @KashinathPatekar Windows 10

Comment: How are you compiling it? Running setup.py automatically sets the paths (if the headers are installed) but o to otherwise the you may need to add an include path yourself.

Comment: corrected grammar: "but otherwise you may need to add an include path yourself"

Comment: Without knowing how you compile, hard to tell what is wrong. Please provide this missing information. One could also use cythonize.

Comment: All the solutions that say `sudo`, `apt-get`, `yum` .etc are for Linux OS (`sudo` is not something you install). Those are not available on Windows, and you will need to setup a compilation env for Windows. How exactly did you run `cython`? The post you linked uses MinGW, and there is an [answer that uses Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42983458/2745495). You'll have to describe your env.

Comment: @DavidW @ead @GinoMempin Windows 10, I install cython by `$ pip install Cython`, and convert the file by changing the `.py` filename extension into `.pyx` then run `cython MY_FILE.pyx` in my command line. I got a `.c` file so I open and compile it with Dev C++, then the error occured.

Comment: You should probably use a setup.py file instead ([start with following the instructions in the basic tutorial](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#cython-hello-world) )

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```bash
sudo updatedb

locate Python.h

export CPATH=/usr/include/python3.5m:$CPATH 

(change your python version here)

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.